# Can I send images back to API.AI?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been working on something using API.AI to create a Google Action that will send random web comics when asked. I have tried and tried, but so far it doesn't seem like there is a good way to put the image's bytes into the JSON response required for API.AI. I might have missed something along the way, but if anyone knows how this can be accomplished that would be of great help. I have been using python if that helps.

Comment: Could you share your python code where you convert images to bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get or put images as a response from Api.ai just put url of that image . Here is some useful docs link :

1. https://docs.api.ai/docs/rich-messages#image
2. https://docs.api.ai/docs/query#section-message-objects